# Perfino. Is there a way to label nodes when using VM pools?

Tags: perfino

Right now I get IP:PORT [generadedId] in node name.
Is there a way to label it like "Service node 1 [generadedId]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible as of perfino 4.0.